Добавление собственного системного вызова в ядро
На паре по системному программированию дали задание, добавить системный вызов в ядро линукс".

Найдите исходный код ядра и откройте файл, содержащий системные вызовы (например, в архитектуре x86 это arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl).
○ Добавьте в таблицу новый системный вызов.

Но беда в том что у меня arm64 архитектура и debian 11 работает через виртуалку UTM, соответственно такого пути к файлу не существует.
Спросил у gpt как найти этот файл с системными вызовами и получил такой ответ:

sudo find / -name entry_64.S
Но мне выдает ошибку:
find: '/run/user/1000/gvfs': permission denied
Вопрос, как мне все таки найти эти системные вызовы



А зачем искать от корня? Искать find-ом надо в лежащем у вас дереве сорсов. Я бы поискал syscalls и посмотрел для каких архитектур что там есть

А ещё исходники надо скачать и распаковать

недавно добавлял в arm32, ядро 4.19 raspbian, таблица в arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl
